# XSL-FO Unnecessary bullets in the list for nested fo:blocks

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have the following xsl-fo list:

```
<fo:list-block>
    <fo:list-item>
        <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
            <fo:block>•</fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:list-item-body>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                <fo:block>text</fo:block>
                <fo:block>text</fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
</fo:list-block>
```

When transforming it into a doc file in the Apache FOP, I get a list with extra bullets:

```
•   text
•   text
•   text
•   text
```

But there must be one bullet

```
•   text
    text
    text
    text
```

I found that this is because the fo:blocks with text are wrapped in a fo:block. But I do not want to delete this block. This problem is reproduced only in DOC documents, but in PDF documents the list is displayed correctly.

I can’t understand if this is a specific of xsl-fo language or Apache FOP formatter problem.

Comment: Since it works correctly for PDF output but not for DOC output, it looks like it's a FOP bug.  Since you've found the workaround of removing the outer `fo:block`, you may need to bite the bullet (pun intended) and remove it.  What does it add that you can't do without?

Comment: This structure is the result of processing a rather complex set of templates. Removing an external block will entail quite a lot of refactoring. I hoped that there was another simpler solution.

Comment: I see your point, but in that case I don't think that there's anything that we can do to help.  You should report it to FOP as a bug and hope that it's fixed soon enough to be useful to you.

Comment: What are you using to do the actual conversion of XSL-FO to DOC with?  FOP does not natively do DOC output, so you must be using a sheet/sheets to do that, and that's surely the source of your problem.  Please clarify.